# Вывод в autocomplete по категориям

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
  <?php 
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT title,date FROM standart LIMIT 10";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        $result_search = array();
        $result_search2 = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result_search[] = $row['title'];   
        $result_search2[] = $row['date'];   
    }

 $res1 = json_encode($result_search); // формирование json
   $res2 = json_encode($result_search2);
  ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var data = [

     { label: <?php echo $res1; ?>, category: "number" }, //вывод в автокомплит 

      { label: <?php echo $res2; ?>, category: "title" }
    ];

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
    minLength: 1    
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Данный скрипт выводит автокомплит по категориям, но выводит все записи из БД в строчку через запятую, например:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

---

а нужно так:

```
1
2
3
4
5




  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[] = array(
        'label' => $row['title'],
        'category'=>'title'
        ); 
$result2[] = array(
        'label' => $row['date'],
        'category'=>'date'
        );      
    }

  ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
 var data = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
    minLength: 1,

    });

  });
  </script>
```

вот куда только $result2 прописать?

Answer (score 1):

В конечном итоге вызов `catcomplete` выглядит следующим образом:

```
$("#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: [
        { label: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], category: "number"},
        { label: ["date 1", "date 2", "date 3", "date 4", "date 5"], category: "title" }
    ],
    minLength: 1    
});
```

Согласно [документации](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), каждый объект из массива `source` станет отдельным элементом выпадающего списка. `label` первого объекта содержит все значения `title` из базы данных, отсюда ошибка.

---

Исправленный код (*не* тестировал):

```
<?php 
  global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT title,date FROM standart LIMIT 10";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        $result = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[] = array('label' => $row['title'], 'value' => $row['date']);   
    }

  ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($result_search); ?>;

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
    minLength: 1    
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: что то в этом есть  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[] = array(
  'label' => $row['title'],
  'category'=>'title'
  ); 
$result2[] = array(
  'label' => $row['date'],
  'category'=>'date'
  );   
    }
  ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
 var data = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
 minLength: 1,
 
    });

  });
  </script>  вот так почти правильно работает, вот куда $result2 прописать?

Comment: _вот куда $result2 прописать?_ — что из себя представляют данные из столбца `data` в БД? они должны попасть в список autocomplete, "рядом" с данными из `title`?